# Where can I locate the values this stored procedure requires?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

`select @@Version` returns

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU11) (KB5003249) - 15.0.4138.2 (X64)   
May 27 2021 17:34:14   
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation 
Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
```

I'm reverse engineering an application here, the original developer is deceased (RIP).

I'm simply trying to add a new user to the database. From what I can tell, the system executes a stored procedure `RS_GetIDValue` and then uses that for the `UserID` of the `rsUser` table instead of using an identity insert. I could be wrong but this is what I'm seeing.

The stored procedure expects a table name to be passed into it but I'm not clear on what values it's expecting for the other params. For example, `@entity_id`, where do I obtain that value from? Same for `@NextID` or is `NextID` the output the stored procedure will generate? If so, then I'd use that value for the new `UserID` when inserting a new user.

```sql
USE [obscure_database_name]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RS_GetIDValue]
    @table_nm varchar(75),
    @entity_id int,
    @NextID INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   SET @NextID = NULL

   IF @entity_id IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN
       SET @NextID = (SELECT id_num
                      FROM IDValue
                      WHERE table_nm = @table_nm
                        AND entity_id = @entity_id);

       UPDATE IDValue
       SET id_num = ISNULL(@NextID + 1, 1)
       WHERE table_nm = @table_nm
         AND entity_id = @entity_id;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @NextID = (SELECT id_num
                       FROM IDValue
                       WHERE table_nm = @table_nm
                         AND entity_id IS NULL);

        UPDATE IDValue
        SET id_num = ISNULL(@NextID + 1, 1)
        WHERE table_nm = @table_nm
          AND entity_id IS NULL;
    END
END
GO
```

I believe I need to execute

```sql
EXEC RS_GetIDValue @table_nm = 'dbo.rsUser', @entity_id = XXXX, @NextID = YYYY;
```

but I don't know what the stored procedure is expecting for **XXXX** and **YYYY**.

Any tips?

**UPDATE**
In response to some of the comments, I didn't know the original developer and in a perfect world, there would be comments and/or documentation. I'm sure the original developer assumed he'd get around to creating the documentation and didn't think he'd die from COVID but I digress.

Currently, this is a very old desktop application that we are trying to determine if we can replicate it making it web (cloud) based. We are trying to make sure we completely understand what the current code is doing. This method for creating IDs is just odd to me and not anything I've see before but again I digress. If we do proceed with refactoring this, insert identity will be used. I hate dealing with triggers and look up tables such as this. I know they serve a purpose but for the kind of web applications I build, identity inserts are fine. /soapbox

**FINAL UPDATE**
Upon an even deeper dive, this rsUser table doesn't rely on this SP, we identified a if/then case elsewhere in the source code in which adding new users is a different and *that* SP actually makes sense.

Thank you to everyone for the assistance. We all thought we were doing mad here but turns out we were making this much more difficult that it actually was.

To Devon, RIP. It's too bad you did not accept the vaccination or worn your mask because I have other questions about your design. Oh, and your family misses you. :/

Comment: Line breaks and white space is a magical thing. The definition of your procedure is impossible to read easily due to the lack of either.

Comment: As for what values are expected, that's what documentation is for; we don't know your database so we have no idea what sort of values the data has.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the formatting. I just noticed that it was off after posting. Regarding the documentation comment, you simply stating that means those values would come from the database or are they user/query supplied?

Comment: As in whomever designed the procedure should have provided documentation for it.

Comment: *"Thanks for correcting the formatting."* I haven't; I'm suggesting you do. Putting all your SQL on a single line like that doesn't make for readable code. Just like this website wouldn't be if everything was on a single line.

Comment: Now we can see the definition, it has problems. For example, you get the value of the next ID by getting the current maximum from the table and adding one. As you don't lock the table, then you could easily suffer race conditions and duplicate values. It'll also reuse values in the event of failed inserts. Why aren't you using a `SEQUENCE` or an `IDENTITY`?

Comment: Personally I would delete this daft procedure and use an `IDENTITY` column like you're supposed to. At the very least use a transaction, you could even do it one statement `UPDATE IDValue SET id_num = ISNULL(id_num + 1, 1), @NextID = id_num WHERE table_nm = @table_nm`. Yes `@NextID` is the output. I note that `@table_nm` should probably be `sysname` or `nvarchar(128)`

Comment: Your procedure supports two levels of "IDs". The sub-level is more like a sequence. An example is a typical "order" where there is a parent table (order) along with a detail table (order_lines). To add an new row to order_lines you pass the PK of the order as the entity id.

Comment: @SMor - thank you for that detail and example, very helpful.